# How many integers between $1$ and $2016$ are divisible by a nontrivial cube $p^3$, $p > 1$?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

How many integers between $1$ and $2016$ are divisible by a nontrivial cube $p^3$, $p > 1$?

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle  http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/InclusionExclusion.shtml

Comment: What have you tried?  There are not many cubes less than $2016$, or even many numbers less than $2016$, so you can just try them all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $13^3 > 2016$. So you want to count the numbers $\leq 2016$ that are divisible by at least one of: $2^3, 3^3, 5^3, 7^3, 11^3$. There is no overlap among these, except for those numbers that are multiples of both $2^3$ and $3^3$ (i.e., numbers divisible by $6^3$), and those numbers that are multiples of both $2^3$ and $5^3$ (i.e., numbers divisible by $10^3$). There is no other double- or triple-counting, since $2 \times 7, 3 \times 5 \geq 13$.

Thus the answer is 
$$[2016/2^3]   + [2016/3^3] + [2016/5^3] + [2016/7^3] + [2016/11^3] -  [2016/6^3] - [2016/10^3] = 252 + 74 + 16 + 5 + 1 - 9 - 2 = 337.$$